# Using SSL over TCP to establish safe connection between two servers with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, ssl, tcp, handshaking

I am trying to send a package from one server to another but i need to be sure that the sender is the "real" one and the package cannot be intercepted, How can i do this using SSL with NodeJS or some other way.

This is what I've done:

Server code:

```
server = tls.createServer(function(c) {
console.log('server connected',

c.authorized ? 'authorized' : 'unauthorized');
});
```

Client code:

```
var tls = require('tls');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
key  : fs.readFileSync('server.key'),
cert : fs.readFileSync('server.crt')
};

var client = tls.connect(9838, options, function () {

console.log(client.authorized ? 'Authorized' : 'Not authorized');

});
```

and this errors out:

```
Error: 101057795:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s23_clnt.c:769:
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this with SSL, properly implemented, by which I mean checking the peer identity after the handshake, and no fudges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ensure that the sender (the client) is the "real" one, you might try using TLS client auth (or mutual authentication).  This means you'll need a client certificate (and key), a server certificate (and key), the CA certificate which issued/signed the server certificate, and the CA certificate which issued/signed the client certificate.

First, your TLS server will need to provide its certificate to any connecting TLS clients; this means you'll need to [configure its certificate and key](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener).  You'll also want the TLS server to request that the client send its certificate to the server, as part of the handshake:

```
var tlsOptions = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-ca-cert.pem'),
  requestCert: true,
  rejectUnauthorized: true
};

var server = tls.createServer(tlsOptions, function () {
```

Then, for the client, you [configure it with its certificate and key](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_connect_options_callback), and the CA certificate which issued/signed the server certificate (so that the client can verify that the receiver is the "real" one):

```
var tlsOptions = {
  host: 'server.example.com',
  port: 9838,
  cert: fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),
  key: fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
  ca: [ fs.readFileSync('server-ca-cert.pem')
};

var client = tls.connect(tlsOptions, function () {
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @kristianzivkovic for sending/receiving JSON over these sockets, you might use something like [`node-json-socket`](https://github.com/sebastianseilund/node-json-socket), which handles the TCP-layer buffering/parsing of payloads.  The fact that your sockets are created using `tls`, not `net`, should not matter to `node-json-socket`.

Comment: can you use the same CA for both the client and server? Or should they be different?